# How to display the content of the Object in ES6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

The filterComment prints [object Object],[object Object]
How to display the content of the object.

```
 var post = {id: 4, title: 'Post Title 4'};
var comments = [
  {postId: 4, content:'Comment for post id 4'},
  {postId: 3, content:'Comment for post id 3'},
  {postId: 1, content:'Comment for post id 1'},
  {postId: 4, content:'Another Comment for post id 4'}
 ];

function commentsForPost(singlePost, allComments)   {
  return allComments.filter(function(comment) {
    console.log('comment Id ' + comment.postId);
    console.log('Post Id ' + singlePost.id);
    return comment.postId === singlePost.id;
  });
}
var filterComment = commentsForPost(post, comments);
`Filter comment ${filterComment}` //console.log this line prints [object Object],[object Object]
```

I expect the content of the filterComment. i.e.  [{"postId":4,"content":"Comment for post id 4"},{"postId":4,"content":"Another Comment for post id 4"}]

Thanks.

Comment: replace `+` with a comma: `console.log('comment Id ', comment.postId);` it should list it as an object with it's content, allowing you to view it in browser console

Comment: You haven't shown how you're printing your object, so I'm assuming a `console.log` call on `filterComment`. You can override your object's [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function to provide your own behaviour, or simply write a function to iterate its properties.

Comment: Yes, console.log. I am looking for something build in js function. Not by overriding the toString. Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? :

```
allComments
.filter(function(comment) {
  console.log('comment Id ' + comment.postId);
  console.log('Post Id ' + singlePost.id);
  return comment.postId === singlePost.id;
})
.map(comment => comment.content);
```

or using ES6 [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), just:

```
.map({ content } => content);
```